# how to construct django Q object matching none

Tags: django, django-q

I wonder which is the correct way to construct a `Q(...)` object which matches no object in the queryset. It seems that both `Q()` and `~Q()` match *all* objects!

Comment: Which is the query you want to do?

Comment: I want to find a q such that M.objects.filter(q) is the same as M.objects.none()

Comment: Why not using EmptyQuerySet?

Comment: Because the filter q is constructed once and used many times. I don't want to put an if...else each time it is used.

Answer (score 17):

`Q(pk__in=[])` should do the trick.

Comment: It's nice to note that the optimizer will correctly simplify complex expressions. Queries for `( Q(pk__in=[]) & Q(foo="bar") ) | Q(hello="world")` will simplify the condition to `WHERE "hello" = world`. It also works with tilde `~` negations. `Q(pk=None)` does not get optimized the same way (presumably because `pk` can be overridden).

Answer (score 7):

`Q(pk=None)` works fine.

`Q(pk__in=[])` works fine as well and doesn't hit the database.